# Energy of vortex-antivortex pair

Tags: energy, vortex, superfluidity

I am given the following field in 2d:

$$\theta(\mathbf{x}) = \phi(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_1) - \phi(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_2),$$

where $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2$ are the position of the vortex and antivortex respectively. I am given the following Hamiltonian or energy:

$$E = \frac{\hbar^2 \rho}{2m} \int d^2 \mathbf{x} (\nabla \theta)^2.$$

I tried to find this energy. I will summarize the work I did. Starting with the gradient in cylindrical coordinates we find:

$$\nabla \theta(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_1|} \Big(-\frac{y-y_1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_1|} \hat{\mathbf{x}} + \frac{x-x_1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_1|}\hat{\mathbf{y}}\Big) - \frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_2|} \Big(-\frac{y-y_2}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_2|} \hat{\mathbf{x}} + \frac{x-x_2}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_2|}\hat{\mathbf{y}}\Big) = \hat{M} \Big(\frac{\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_1|^2} - \frac{\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_2}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_2|^2} \Big),$$

where $\hat{M}$ is the orthogonal matrix with entries $M_{11} = M_{22} = 0$ and $M_{21} = - M_{12} = 1$. Since $\hat{M}$ is orthogonal we know that we may write:

$$(\nabla \theta)^2 = \Big(\frac{\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_1|^2} - \frac{\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_2}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_2|^2} \Big)^2 = \frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_1|^2} + \frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_2|^2} - 2 \frac{(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_1)\cdot (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_2)}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_1|^2|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_2|^2}.$$

The integrals over the first two terms are quite simple but the last term is quite hard to calculate. I tried to write the following:

$$\frac{(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_1)\cdot (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_2)}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_1|^2|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_2|^2} = \nabla \mathrm{ln}|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_1| \cdot \nabla \mathrm{ln}|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_2| = \nabla (\mathrm{ln}|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_1| \nabla |\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_2|) - \Delta \mathrm{ln}|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_2|\mathrm{ln}|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_2|,$$

I am given that $\Delta \mathrm{ln}|\mathbf{x}|=0$ if $\mathbf{x} \neq \mathbf{0}$ and that there is a minimal radius $\xi$ for the integration to ensure convergence of the integral and describe the physics. I have no clue how to integrate over this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\nabla^2 \ln |{\bf x}|= -2\pi \delta^2({\bf x})
$$
This is just a disguised version of the computation of the potential energy of a pair of  two-dimensional point  charges.

Comment: Thank you. But how can you include the factor $\xi$ using this expression?

Comment: the usual way is to include it in the log as $\ln (|{\bf x}|/\xi)$.