# Energy cost for pair of vortices

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, many-body, topological-order

How should I derive the expression for the energy associated with the formation of a pair of vortices located at $\vec{r}_{1}$ and $\vec{r}_{2}$ in the classical two-dimensional $XY$-model, given by

$E_{pair}(\vec{r}_{1},\vec{r}_{2})=-2\pi Jn_{1}n_{2}ln{\mid\frac{\vec{r}_{1}-\vec{r}_{2}}{a}\mid}$?

$J$, $n_{1}$, $n_{2}$ and $a$ denote the lattice coupling, the strength of the two vortices and the lattice spacing, respectively.

Comment: answered already: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/543104/energy-of-vortex-antivortex-pair

Comment: @mike Well that question hasn't been really answered I think

Comment: What more do you need? The map from your actual lattice spacing  to the constant $a$ in your formula is the only tricky part. For square lattices it involves a $K_0$ Bessel. The log bit is easy, but I'm willing to explain, if it is not obvious to you.

Comment: @mikestone Yes, that would be nice. However, my homework hints suggest performing a keyhole integral

Comment: What integral are they asking to be done?

Comment: @mikestone I should integrate the mixed terms in which the field arising from one vortex is multiplied with the gradient of the field arising from the other one along a contour which is branch cut along the Re axis of the complex plane

Comment: This is overkill.. The energy cost is that of kinetic energy only. This is identical to energy of  electric field of a pair of point charges in two D. The potential of such a 2D charge is a logarithm. Problem finished. No integration necessary unless you need the constant $a$.